# Understanding std::swap for both pointers and std::vectors

Tags: c++, swap

I have the following toy example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


int main(){


    std::vector<int> a={1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b={4, 5, 6};

    int* pa = a.data();
    int* pb = b.data();

    std::swap(pa,pb);
    std::cout<<"after std::swap(pa,pb)\n";
    std::cout<<"a= "<<a[0]<<" "<<a[1]<<" "<<a[2]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"b= "<<b[0]<<" "<<b[1]<<" "<<b[2]<<"\n";

    std::cout<<"pa= "<<pa[0]<<" "<<pa[1]<<" "<<pa[2]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"pb= "<<pb[0]<<" "<<pb[1]<<" "<<pb[2]<<"\n";

    std::swap(a,b);

    std::cout<<"after std::swap(a,b)\n";
    std::cout<<"a= "<<a[0]<<" "<<a[1]<<" "<<a[2]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"b= "<<b[0]<<" "<<b[1]<<" "<<b[2]<<"\n";

    std::cout<<"pa= "<<pa[0]<<" "<<pa[1]<<" "<<pa[2]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"pb= "<<pb[0]<<" "<<pb[1]<<" "<<pb[2]<<"\n";
}
```

What happens after swap(pa,pb) is clear to me, I expect pa points to b.data(), however after swap(a,b), I expect b.data() now points to "1 2 3", but this is not the case when printing out pa[0], pa[1], pa[2]...

Comment: I don't think you can (legally) access data through old `.data()` pointer after move it

Comment: @appleapple yes you can, the container is still in a valid, yet undefined state after moving

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot if it's undefined state, why old `.data()` pointer keep valid?

Comment: Well, I could be null, It could be a pointer to a new array, It could be pointing to the old data again. The standard says that the value assigned to moved-from objects from `std` will have a valid state, but says nothing about the actual value it should take. If you want them to have a defined value, you can assign them an empty value `a = std::vector{}`

Comment: @Yakk sorry, changed...

Answer (score 3):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap notes that:

> All iterators and references remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

that means memory allocations stay same, vector fields swaps

```
  std::vector<int> a={1, 2, 3}; // data lays at pa
  std::vector<int> b={4, 5, 6}; // data lays at pb

  int* c = a.data(); // == pa
  int* d = b.data(); // == pb

  std::swap(c,d); // c == pb, d == pa
  std::cout<<"after std::swap(c,d)\n";
  std::cout<<"a= "<<a[0]<<" "<<a[1]<<" "<<a[2]<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"b= "<<b[0]<<" "<<b[1]<<" "<<b[2]<<"\n";

  std::cout<<"c= "<<c[0]<<" "<<c[1]<<" "<<c[2]<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"d= "<<d[0]<<" "<<d[1]<<" "<<d[2]<<"\n";

  std::swap(a,b); // c == pb, d == pa, a == pb, b == pa

  std::cout<<"after std::swap(a,b)\n";
  std::cout<<"a= "<<a[0]<<" "<<a[1]<<" "<<a[2]<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"b= "<<b[0]<<" "<<b[1]<<" "<<b[2]<<"\n";

  std::cout<<"c= "<<c[0]<<" "<<c[1]<<" "<<c[2]<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"d= "<<d[0]<<" "<<d[1]<<" "<<d[2]<<"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

A vector tends to be implemented with a pointer to the data. So, let's say there is a place in memory called `foo` which *is* the starting location for `{1, 2, 3}` and `bar` which *is* the starting location for `{4, 5, 6}`

```
std::vector<int> a={1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b={4, 5, 6};
```

`a` is a vector that has a pointer that points to `foo`
`b` is a vector that has a pointer that points to `bar`

```
int* c = a.data();
int* d = b.data();
```

`c` is a pointer that points to what `a`'s pointer is currently pointing to; `foo`
`d` is a pointer that points to what `b`'s pointer is currently pointing to; `bar`

Now, let's do some swapping...

```
std::swap(c, d);
```

`c` is a pointer that now points to what `d` was pointing to; `bar`
`d` is a pointer that now points to what `c` was pointing to; `foo`
So `c` will now point to `{4, 5, 6}` and `d` will now point to `{1, 2, 3}`

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

`a`'s pointer now points to what `b`'s pointer was pointing to; `bar`
`b`'s pointer now points to what `a`'s pointer was pointing to; `foo`
Swapping the vectors swaps what they're pointing at; it does not swap the actual data inside.